# Why did Jigsaw test Art Blank two times in Saw 4?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw, saw-4

In [Saw 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_IV), Art is a lawyer involved in a housing development project with John Kramer and Jill Tuck before the events that would turn John into Jigsaw. Art is targeted by Jigsaw for successfully defending guilty people in his role as lawyer, including Brenda (a pimp), Ivan (a rapist) and Rex (an abusive husband).

But why was Art Blankin tested two times?
I mean he passed one test then he should be free, why did Jigsaw shedule a second task for him? It doesn't even fit into trend of assigning series of tasks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the traps that makes the least sense in the series.

Taken in account that it was Gordon that sewed Trevor's eyes shut, and Hoffman does not know that Gordon is working with Jigsaw, we can determine this is a Jigsaw trap, probably one of his last as there is not even a tape at the beginning, the trap just starts.

In the [saw wiki](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Saw_IV)

> In a later flashback, Art finds two items waiting for him elsewhere in the mausoleum: a recorded message from Jigsaw and an envelope containing instructions.)

It can be determined, due to the new trend of having a person go through a series of tests for freedom, that this was part of that process, and Art was simply continuing with his series of tests that started out in the mausoleum.

---

It might also be possible that Hoffman didn't know the test even took place, looking into John's history and captured Art on his own accord in order to have someone as a Zepp-like pawn for his test against Rigg.

Comment: The last line of your answer doesn't make sense because all the traps of Saw-4 are designed or at-least scheduled by jigsaw then doubling of efforts not possible.

Comment: With having 3 accomplices at the time and noting the fact that they are, more or less counted on to be independent and to succeed Jigsaw, combined with him being bedridden and in need of serious brain surgery, it is entirely plausable that all traps in 3 AND 4 are set up by Hoffman, and not Jigsaw.  He merely plans (if he is even capable of that, at this point).

Comment: Jigsaw's capabilities are always shown unrealistic in saw series. I mean in the end of Saw 3 and 4 we see that he takes a tape inside his stomach to warn Hoffman. That means he knows about every task of Hoffman.And he is well capable of planing. And even Hoffman selected the same person for traps as selected by Jigsaw and even the same traps. Accept for Jigsaw's wife.